# Usage of of jquery Bind method that I never seen before

Tags: jquery

Trying to get comfortable with jQuery and I have encountered some sample code that I am having trouble understanding. It refers to the bind method and the way they use it. Here it is

```
$('textControl').bind(($.browser.opera ? 'keypress', 'keydown') + '.autocomplete', function(event) { code...});
```

I understand the selection of either keypress or keydown but what I dont understand is why they attach the .autocomplete on the even handler name?

if anyone can shed some light that would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a features of jQuery called **[Namespaced Evenets](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events)** which is often used within Plugins as it allows an easy and quick way for a plugin to only manipulate it's own events.

Comment: Thanks for clarification and the category this falls under, very helpful

Answer (score 11):

Let me explain, step by step.

```
$('textControl').bind(
```

binding to textControl

```
($.browser.opera ? 'keypress', 'keydown')
```

tertiary expression returning keypress if the browser is opera, keydown otherwise.

```
'.autocomplete'
```

Autocomplete is a custom event the jQuery plugin adds to the keypress event object. So basically they just grouped it in to make it a bit more organized but it's a custom namespace event.

So in reality, the event is attached to keypress/keydown, but you can bind and unbind using the namespace, keeping the workspace organized.

Comment: thanks to your step by step clarification, makes a lot of sense now.