# Where is "contextmenu.slickgrid" fired in SlickGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

I'm going through the slickgrid code and trying to write a small wrapper for our team. As I was going through the code, I observed that there are several custom events on canvas and headScroller like "keydown.slickgrid", "click.slickgrid", "dblclick.slickgrid", "contextmenu.slickgrid". From the knowledge I have in jQuery this event should be fired using $.trigger somewhere in the code. But, I don't see this anywhere. Adding to my surprise, I've search the entire source of this page > http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example7-events.html <, I don't see any event fired triggered explicitly, but everything works. Can someone demystify this part of code?

PS: Really liked Slickgrid and I appreciate it's extensibility.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/911552

Comment: @JonathanLonowski...correct! Exactly what I was looking for. "Namespaced Events in Jquery." Thanks for the help! Please post a complete answer so that I can accept.